# How do I read OneNote indented paragraphs using OneNote Javascript APIs?

Tags: javascript, office-js, onenote-api

I have a notebook that contains these
[image]

The docs for OneNote APIs are here (paragraph class selected already) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/onenote/onenote.paragraph?view=onenote-js-1.1

If I run this code:

```
export async function run() {
  try {
    await OneNote.run( async context => {
      var page = context.application.getActivePage();
      var pageContents = page.contents;
      var firstPageContent = pageContents.getItemAt(0);
      var paragraphs=firstPageContent.outline.paragraphs
      //firstPageContent.delete()
      //var out_line=firstPageContent.outline
      paragraphs.load('richText/text');




      // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
      return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
              //debugger;
              console.log("Items",paragraphs.items);
              for (var i=0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++)
                {
                  var paragraph= paragraphs.items[i] 
                  paragraph.load('items')
                  context.sync()   
                  console.log(paragraph.richText.text)
                  show_next_level(paragraph,i)
                }

          });


    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
}
}

export async function show_next_level(paragraph,i) {
  try {
    await OneNote.run( async context => {
      //debugger;
      //var paragraphs=par.paragraphs
      var paragraphs=paragraph.paragraphs
      paragraphs.load('richText/text');
      //console.log("Items",paragraphs.items);


      // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
      return context.sync()
        .then(function () {

          console.log("Items",paragraphs.items);
          for (var i=0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++)
            {
              var paragraph= paragraphs.items[i] 
              paragraph.load()

              context.sync()  
              console.log(paragraph.richText.text)
              debugger;
              //paragraph.richText.text=paragraph.richText.text+'►'
              show_next_level(paragraph,i)
            }

          });


    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
}
}
```

After multiple iterations I managed to read the next level of indentation but I am still getting an error. The output of the above is now

```
Items (4) [h, h, h, h]
One line 1 
One line 2
One line 3
One line 4
Items [h]
Two line 0
Items (3) [h, h, h]
Two line 1
Two line 2
Two line 3
Items []
5taskpane.js:192 Error: PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your are not waiting for Item Promises, so, It throws `PropertyNotLoaded` Error. It happens because you are not waiting for the **context sync** eg. in the line:

```js
context.sync() // It's a promise, so it requires .then() method
console.log(paragraph.richText.text)
debugger;
```

The following code works for multiple indented lines and uses `await/async` methods to wait for promises:

```js
export async function run() {
  try {
    await OneNote.run(async (context) => {
      var page = context.application.getActivePage();
      var pageContents = page.contents;
      var firstPageContent = pageContents.getItemAt(0);
      var paragraphs = firstPageContent.outline.paragraphs;

      paragraphs.load('richText/text');

      // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
      await context.sync();

      // Foreach level 0 paragraph
      for (let paragraph of paragraphs.items) {
        // Read the paragraph
        await readParagraph(context, paragraph, 0);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
  }
}

// Read Paragraph data and Child data
async function readParagraph(context, paragraph, level) {
  try {
    paragraph.load('items');

    await context.sync();
    console.log('Level ' + level + ' > Data:', paragraph.richText.text);

    let levelParagraphs = paragraph.paragraphs;
    levelParagraphs.load('richText/text');

    await context.sync();

    for (let p of levelParagraphs.items) {
      await readParagraph(context, p, level + 1);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in Level ' + level, error);
  }
}
```

I used [these data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsaEn.png) for testing and [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCqm0.png) were the results.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: thank you! I will have a look later today or tomorrow and I will confirm that it works for me, I really appreciate the help

Comment: Worked, thank you, for a guy who started with Javascript like a week ago I was pretty close to the final solution. I am still chewing at the way the Promises work