# OneNote Office.js APIs: Updating the text of a paragraph and indenting it as needed

Tags: office-js, onenote

I thought this would be a simple task after I learn how to traverse the structure of a OneNote page.

A simple page will have an outline (that is the quivalent of a div html tag) and this outline will contain paragraphs (the p tag). Now the interesting part is coming, OneNote can indent paragraphs, this way the indented paragraph gets added to the collection of subparagraphs its predecessor has. This is easier said than done

The APIs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/onenote/onenote.paragraph?view=onenote-js-1.1).

Basically **paragraph.paragraphs.items** is the collection of paragraphs that are children of a paragraph. Each paragraph object has a property called parentParagraph which I can't figure out how to use.

So the idea would be to take an existing paragraph and move it as

```
ParagraphL1
     ParagraphL2
     ParagraphL3
```

should turn into

```
   ParagraphL1
     ParagraphL2
          ParagraphL3
```

For the above to happen I guess `paragraph2.items[0]=paragraph3`. I am not sure what is happening with the reference that paragraph1 has for paragraph3 as being one of its children

The other thing that I can't figure out is how to update the text of a paragraph with a new text. It seems that with the current APIs there no other way to do it other than adding a sibling of the existing one and deleting the existing one

### Update

I have tried to move 'test' under Level11 (see the bottom of the picture for structure and IDs, see the console output, last three lines

So adding the test paragraph to **Level11.items** succeeded but it did not have the effect I expected; as you can see in the Watch window  Level11 indicates it has child with test's ID but test does not indicate Level11 as its parent (see the IDs at the bottom and in the watch window

[image: out of sync pointers]

### Summary

In one sentence: I need to be able to indent/outdent any arbitrary paragraph in a OneNote document using JavaScript APIs. Start from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272535/how-do-i-read-onenote-indented-paragraphs-using-onenote-javascript-apis) if you wish.

Comment: Your link to the APIs is broken. Don't but it in back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the OneNote APIs, but it seems that the `paragraph.richtext.text` property is read only. So, I think your idea to add sibling is the right one. For similar reasons, I think that to indent, you need to insert a child paragraph (that duplicates the original paragraph) one level down and then delete the original paragraph.

Comment: quite convoluted way to do it, They could have made the parentParagraph writable

Comment: I have tried the reverse, that was to make 'test' a sibling of Level11 (see the picture in the update)  and see the comments there

Comment: Are you using the `Paragraph.insert*AsSibling` methods or are you trying to directly push objects onto the paragraphs.items array? I think you have to use the insert methods.

Comment: I considered that too but that works for a paragraph that has no subsequent children. What I want is to indent or un-indent a paragraph and all its children. The method you are suggesting works when you add text or html before or after a paragraph,

Comment: Was the bounty attributed to you ? This is so unfair, I lost 200 points and I have no pertinent answer to this

Comment: No. I have not received the bounty.

Comment: where the heck did it go then?

Comment: I don't know how bounties work in Stack. I'm trying to find some help for your question internally at Microsoft.

Comment: oh you are Microsoft? Thanks God someone is looking at this in the end. I opened an issue here as well. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1209 I am planning to develop an application around note and I need all the help I can get. I have tried various ways -REST API and then JavaScript but nothing helps. I will be forever indebted to you if you could put me in touch with someone I could ask questions..there seems to be a huge void in this space (OneNote JavaScript API examples)

Comment: The above link is wrong, this is the github issue I was referring to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1217